# Tokenizing in C without strtok()

Tags: c, regex, token, tokenize

I am trying to tokenize an input string based on the criteria that a token is defined as either a quoted string, a set of non-space characters, or a `|` character.  Obviously, in this case `strtok` will not work so I was thinking maybe using regex? Or perhaps there is a simpler solution I haven't thought of yet?

Has anyone run into this before or perhaps even have a suggestion as to how I could approach this? Thanks!

Comment: Write a custom lexer in the form of a finite state machine. Your grammar is very simple, it will be reasonably easy.

Comment: When asking for a regex solution, please include a list of items you want to match and another list of items you would like to omit.

Comment: Why wouldn't `strtok` work? You can specify multiple delimiters.

Comment: As far as `strtok` is concerned: for CSV's you _can_ tokenize using `",;|\t\r\n"`, each char is a delimiter... quoted strings might be easier when dealing with `strtok_r`, though

Comment: Can the quoted string contain escape sequences?  i.e. how do you include a `"` in a string, and do you need to translate things like `\n`?

Comment: Everything will be on one line, so no need to deal with \n. As for ", I would do \"

Comment: So, you do need to convert the two character sequence `\"` in the input string to the single character `"` in the token.  What about other two character sequences (`\t`, ``\\``, etc...). The point is that it's not just a matter of delimiting the tokens, it's also a matter of transforming the input string into the token value.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, why will `strtok()` 'obviously' not work? You seem to be implying that `strtok()` cannot work with multiple delimiters; it does (the `char * delim` is a pointer to a set of delimeters). That's a reasonable way to start if you want to build it from scratch. Using a regexp is one stage up, however still 'building from scratch'.

However, if you don't want to build it from scratch, look at `lex` (or `flex`) which will build you a tokenise in C from a `lex` source file.

Comment: I believe strtok() would not work because if I have the following string: abc "this is fun", the tokenized output would be: abc, "this, is, fun" instead of the output I'm looking for, which is: abc, this is fun

Comment: `strtok` would not handle the quoted strings for you automatically, but you could (for instance) use `strtok` to find delimiter boundaries, and those delimeters would be variable. Whilst not parsing a string constant, you could look for whitespace and `"` as delimiters. Whilst parsing string constants, you'd look for only a `"` as a delimeter. `strtok()` is just a glorified `for` loop that searches for one of a set of characters and inserts a `\0`; you will need something like this if you are writing your own parser. For an easier life, use `lex` (or `flex`).

Answer (score 0):

Do people still use lex and yacc? If not, you might want to create a state machine yourself and use your input one character at a time to feed the state machine to consume your input. That's what lex would do anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Do your own parser. A regex is usually used for more complex expression than this, but it's a good idea.

You should check char by char and use conditions to determine if it's a token or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try out a regex fast and with the input you will later use it on, try out [regexr](http://www.regexr.com/).
You can paste your input and it shows you what your regex matches.